# Determine voltage of PWM signal with only a multimeter

Tags: led, pwm, multimeter

For my new project, I'm trying to convert an old LED computer monitor (the Dell SE2717H) into a cool lamp by stripping everything but the LED panel.

The LED panel is currently driven by a big power circuit board which I would like to replace by a simple power supply. My problem is, I can't seem to figure out the voltage at which the LED are powered. When I put my multimeter on one of the 6 wires going to the LED panel, it reads 0.5v. I'm assuming this is because the LEDs are driven using PWM.

My question is, therefore, is there any way to figure out the nominal voltage of these LEDs using only a multimeter ?

Cheers!

The picture of the board. The wires going to the panel are 6 pins at the very top of the board

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but be aware you can buy a [Crappy oscilloscope kit](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002003035838.html?src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=708-803-3821&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=9309943343&albag=90987094781&trgt=296730740870&crea=en1005002003035838&netw=u&device=c&albpg=296730740870&albpd=en1005002003035838&gclid=CjwKCAjw9MuCBhBUEiwAbDZ-7q5ue9hmoTkCL0ZDtHWQuGofa5L_60f-oHv1jAoQpwLGVFVwzDEP-BoCd1YQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) on Aliexpress for about 25 currency.

Comment: Nominal voltage isn't interesting; to control brightness, it's average current that should be measured (and these displays have dimming control, there's a range setting to be fiddled with).

Answer (score 1):

The LED voltage seems to be on the low side of the driver. This ranges from the Off state of the LEDs (Vcc-VLeds) (<1V?)  and the On state of the FET switch (50 mV??)

So making a TACH circuit for your DMM you can make a crude estimate of the inverse PWM since you are sensing from the bottom side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAqS5w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Does that not seem very little (1v) for LEDs like this ? I'm more used to seing the 3 to 12v range

Comment: It seems you are measuring a different circuit with low side switching rather than high side 12V. Find the other side to confirm. If my analysis is correct, this answer is the simplest way to measure D